# How is it possible for a word to display in Google organic results, when that word is not present in the HTML document?

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

When you search for "Hosting" in google.co.in, I get www.hostingraja.in in the first page. But instead of displaying the title in the index page, it shows "Hosting Raja", this word itself is not not there in the index page.

When the word "Hosting Raja" is not there in the index page, where does Google pick up the word?

[image: Google Search result]

Answer (score 2):

When you write the title tag, Google doesn't guarantee that it will display the tag as you wrote it. Search engines can rewrite the title tag based on a number of factors, such as the tag itself, on-page content, and what they think best describes the page. But we can point them in the right direction and improve our chances.

In your website's case, Google chose to rewrite your tag. The actual title tag is long, stuffed with keywords, and confusing:

> Hosting | Web Hosting India | No.1 Web Hosting Company in India |
>   Cheap / Low Price Hosting

You should consider rewriting your tag to comply with recommended best practices, as outlined here:

https://moz.com/learn/seo/title-tag

So if you keep your tag to about 60 characters total, including branding, it may look something like this:

Hosting Raja | Best Cheap Web Hosting in India

(You get the idea.)

Again, there are no guarantees with search engines, but you better your chances by following their preferred format.